# Run character count javascript function in single page only

Tags: javascript

I have a page which has form to edit information. I wrote a simple javascript code to count character as soon as this page is loaded. So i put `<body onload='charCount()'>`. It works just fine but the problem is when other pages are loaded, i got javascript error: can't get value from element id=title. My entire website using the same header and footer and the body tag is in the header.

Is there anyway to run this javascript on that particular page only? I tried to put `<form onload='charCount()'>` also but i did not work.

Here is my html page:

```
<html>
<body onload='charCount()'>
....//end header section
<form>
<input id='title' type='text' value='abcd'/>
<div id='showcharcount'></div>
</form> //end content section
<script>
function charCount(){
var x = document.getElementById("title").value;
document.getElementById("showcharacount").innerHTML = charCountFunc(x) + "/35   characters allowed";
}
function charCountFunc(x) {
var n = x.length;
return n;
}
</script>
</body>
</html> //end footer section
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to run the script code on one page, and not on other pages, you can ensure that the script is attached to the said page only. Not on other page because that would be a part of garbage, code which is not used.

You can use `window.onload = functionName;` command which calls the function `functionName()` when the page got loaded.

Just add the next script at the webpage of which you want to *use* the function.

```
<script>
    function charCount(){
        ...
    }
    function charCountFunc(x) {
        ...
    }
    window.onload = charCount;
</script>
```

It can be done on the server side, by adding the above snippet in the template showing the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the error by checking existence of the element first.

```
function charCount(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("title");
    if (elem != null) {
        var x = elem.value;
        document.getElementById("showcharacount").innerHTML = charCountFunc(x) + "/35   characters allowed";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great suggestion, however, is there anyway to run the js when only a particular page is loaded? content page is loaded using get paremeter from index.php file... many thanks...Anyway this is very great suggestion.

Comment: If you only have a single page on which you need to run this function, then @KarelG's answer is the way to go. If you need to run this on several pages, then validating existence of the element would allow you to avoid duplicating the same JavaScript.